# Bash - looping through INI sections

Tags: bash, for-loop, ini

my question is about how to read an ini file with a number of sections and feed the section values into variables in a loop.

Here's my **batch.ini** file

```
[section1]
val1='/home/test/'
val2='-i -200 -j 400%'

[section2]
val1='/home/test2/'
val2='-i -320 -j 333%'

[section3]
val1='/home/test3/'
val2='-i -223 -j 555%'
```

In my bash script I’d like to loop through the sections one at a time and assign the values to variables in my bash script. My pseudocode would be like this:

```
for sectionx = 1 to (number of sections)
do
   my_var1=sectionx(val1)
   my_var2=sectionx(val2)
   echo $my_var1 
   echo $my_var2 
done
```

Output:

```
/home/test/
-i -200 -j 400%
/home/test2/
-i -320 -j 333%
/home/test3/
-i -223 -j 555%
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your existing code? For the record, when I did this, I ended up using awk, and that was a nice, horrible kludge. Next time, I would just use perl.

Comment: @Tanktalus There is a pseudocode at the least. But what you have suggested seems the right approach.

Comment: The "what have you tried" bit was more about the `sectionx(...)` pseudo-call than the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to read `.ini` files in bash, I suggest you use an already implemented solution, for example [Bash ini parser](https://github.com/rudimeier/bash_ini_parser) by rudimeier works perfectly.

There are also other options, like [shini](https://github.com/wallyhall/shini)  or the parser by [albfan](https://github.com/albfan/bash-ini-parser).

Using the one by rudimeier you will get all the values in bash variables named accordingly.

For example for your ini

```
[section1]
val1='/home/test/'
val2='-i -200 -j 400%'

[section2]
val1='/home/test2/'
val2='-i -320 -j 333%'

[section3]
val1='/home/test3/'
val2='-i -223 -j 555%'
```

You will get the following bash variables:

```
INI__ALL_SECTIONS='section1 section2 section3'
INI__ALL_VARS='INI__section1__val1 INI__section1__val2 INI__section2__val1 INI__section2__val2 INI__section3__val1 INI__section3__val2'
INI__NUMSECTIONS=3

INI__section1__val1=/home/test/
INI__section1__val2='-i -200 -j 400%'
INI__section2__val1=/home/test2/
INI__section2__val2='-i -320 -j 333%'
INI__section3__val1=/home/test3/
INI__section3__val2='-i -223 -j 555%'
```

With this you can iterate over sections and variables, for example:

```
for section in $INI__ALL_SECTIONS; do 
  echo "Variables in $section:"; 
  for var in `declare | grep "^INI__"$section"__"`; do 
    echo $var; 
  done; 
done;
```

Will yield:

```
Variables in section1:
INI__section1__val1=/home/test/
INI__section1__val2='-i -200 -j 400%'

Variables in section2:
INI__section2__val1=/home/test2/
INI__section2__val2='-i -320 -j 333%'

Variables in section3:
INI__section3__val1=/home/test3/
INI__section3__val2='-i -223 -j 555%'
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I actually tried this already and it worked to read my .ini file into a set of variables, however, I could not see a way to programmatically address the variables in a for loop:


`for ((i=1;ini_sec<=${INI__NUMSECTIONS};i++));
do
    echo "section1 var1 = ${INI__section1__var1}"
done`

Comment: Aside from being a link-only answer, that project has a few problems and doesn't appear to be maintained. (Lots of pending pull requests and open issues, with no significant activity in over 6 years.)

Comment: @ThatDude calling this a "link only answer" is a bit degrading. Personally I see this as a "don't reinvent the wheel" answer. There are many options as I mentioned (many more than the ones I linked). The solution works fine as explained in my edit. I *could* write new code that does exactly what OP is asking for, but why would I? Someone else has already done that and it works and fulfills OP's needs.

Comment: @brunorey I didn't call it anything, maybe you meant to address^^
That aside thank you so much for your answer, it's the most complete by far. I've copied your sample `for loop` but it doesn't output anything for me, I'm using the default `INI__` configuration in case that's relevant.

`echo "section1 var1 = ${INI__section1__var1}"` outputs as exepeted.

Comment: You're right, I was trying to address the other user and mistakenly put your name there. About the loop: sorry, there was a problem with my code. I've updated, check again please.

Comment: I've just realised that it cannot handle the spaces in data of **INI__section1__val2**. No matter how I quote that line it gets broken up into separate lines.  Is that something happening in the grep?

Comment: I solved this by adding `IFS=$'\n'` before the second `for...loop`. All working fine now. Thanks @brunorey

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the problem of processing .ini files and came up with this solution.

It uses a single `awk` call to get a response suitable for creating an associative array using `declare -A` of property/value pairs for a given section in the .ini file. This can then be queried to get the value, or iterated over and used to create and assign values to variables.

It's general enough that it shouldn't be much of a problem adapting to various scenarios.

Here's a testing script demonstrating the `awk` and `declare` statements used;

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Parse a INI style properties file and extract property values for a given section
# 
# Author: Alan Carlyle
# License: CC0 (https://creativecommons.org/about/cclicenses/)
#
# Example Input: (example.properties)
#  [SEC1]
#  item1=value1
#  item2="value 2"
#
#  [Section 2]
#  property 1="Value 1 of 'Section 2'"
#  property 2='Single "quoted" value'
#
# Usage:  
# $ read_props example.properties "Section 2" property\ 2
# $ Single "quoted" value
#
# Section names and properties with spaces do not need to be quoted. 
# Values with spaces must be quoted. Values can use single or double quotes.
# The following characters [ = ] can not be used in names or values.
#
# If the property is not provided the the whole section is outputed.
#

propertiesFile=$1
section=$2
property=$3

# Extract the propetites for the section formated as for associtive array
sectionData="( "$(awk -F'=' -v s="$section" '/^\[/{ gsub(/[\[\]]/, "", $1); f = ($1 == s); next } 
    NF && f{ print "["$1"]="$2 }' $propertiesFile)" )"

# Create associtive array from extracted section data
declare +x -A "properties=$sectionData"

if [ -z "$property" ] 
then
  echo $sectionData
else
  echo ${properties[$property]}
fi
```